# Is the following procedure for antacid titration correct?

Tags: acid-base, titration

I'm trying to check which antacid is more effective by determining the amount of $\ce{HCl}$ they can neutralize.

- Take $\pu{10 mL}$ antacid suspension and add excess $\pu{1 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$.
- Back titrate the excess 1M $\ce{HCl}$ with 1M $\ce{NaOH/Na2CO3}$.
- Do the required calculations.

Also, can I directly titrate the antacid with $\ce{HCl}$? Some solids remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should titrate to pH 6 (the pH at the entrance to the small intestine, 7.4 (the end of the small intestine) and 4.5. Multiply the mL of HCl used by its normality to get the mEq of protons absorbed by the antacid. Multiply the pH 4.5 result by 84 to get the sodium bicarbonate equivalent (mg of NaHCO3 that neutralizes the same amount of acid as the test sample).

The antacid may contain some insoluble material (such as SiO2) but try to get everything dissolved. Also, when titrating wait a good long time before accepting the pH reading